# How to implement push notifications in Cordova Platform?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications

I am trying to implement the push notifications concept in my app.
After successful installation of plugin, `push.on(registration)` method is not calling

My Project structure is `projectname/platforms/android/assets/www`

In `www` folder contains all `html,js,css` files

`notification.js` file, I have called in `homepage.html`

I have written the code in **notification.js** is:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', pushNotification, false);
function PushNotification(){
var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "GCMProjectId(123456789)"},"ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );
       push.on('registration', function(data) {
            alert("registration id is:"+data.registrationId);
            var id = localStorage.getItem("userId");
            var notifyInput = {
                        "token":data.registrationId,
                        "type":"android",
                        "uid":id
               }
            });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
              alert(data.message);
            });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
            // e.message
            alert("error function calling on push notifications");

            });

}
```

Here, `push.on(registration) and push.on(notification)` the method is not calling please let us know the possible ways to get the notification for a specific device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After successful installation of push notification plugin, i have received the notification in Android

**Process:**

By using the below link i have installed the push-notification plugin

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

**Installation Requirements:**

-Android version > 6.0.0 
-iOS Version > 4.3.0 better

For iOS Version, pods required.so we need to install pod

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

For GCM Registration:
    https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

After succesfull installation, pod file will be created . Once it done the open the `project.xcworkspace` file. Then ios app will run properly

If you are calling the notification in middle of the app, then write the `addEventListener` method

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', pushNotification, false);

    function PushNotification(){
    var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "xxxxxx(refers project number in GCM)"},"ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );

           push.on('registration', function(data) {
                alert("registration id is:"+data.registrationId);
               // registration id need to pass your notification server

                });

        push.on('notification', function(data) {
                  alert(data.message);
                  // you receive the notification
                });

        push.on('error', function(e) {
                // e.message
                alert("error function calling on push notifications");

                });

    }
```